# function of (ws.Run "mshta vbscript:ClipboardData.SetData)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
ws.Run "mshta vbscript:ClipboardData.SetData(" & Chr(34) & "text" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Name & Chr(34) & ")(close)", 0, True
```

what function of above code?

below is the full code

```
Sub sendmessages(ByVal row As Integer)
    i = row
    Set ws2 = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws2.AppActivate "Î¢ÐÅ"
    ws2.SendKeys "^%w"
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Rem Being executed cells(3+i,1)
    
    Name = Cells(3 + i, 2).Value
    Msg = Cells(3 + i, 3)
    
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.Run "mshta vbscript:ClipboardData.SetData(" & Chr(34) & "text" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Name & Chr(34) & ")(close)", 0, True
    Sleep 999
    ws.SendKeys "^f"   'ctrl find'
    Sleep 999
    ws.SendKeys "^v"  'ctrl paste'
    Sleep 999
    ws.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Sleep 555
    ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    Sleep 555
    ws.Run "mshta vbscript:ClipboardData.SetData(" & Chr(34) & "text" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Msg & Chr(34) & ")(close)", 0, True
    Sleep 500
    ws.SendKeys "^v"
    Sleep 300
    ws.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any other way besides << ws.Run "mshta vbscript:ClipboardData.SetData >>?       My aim is to copy the table of excel and paste at another app.

Comment: now the program only can copy the value of cell, and paste on other app